# Routing traffic around VPN

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn

I recently setup a OpenVPN client on my HTPC, however once I connected to the VPN server I was no longer able to remotely SSH or connect to the other servers I had running on the HTPC.

I followed the advice given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/515272/openvpn-bypass-on-some-ports) and [here](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=50114&sid=b440414422596bb7dbc96cf7c9ee511f#p50114) on how to route incoming traffic appropriately and was able to connect through SSH once again. These are the results,

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.24.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       172.20.24.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.20.24.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
198.144.158.43  192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0   

$ ip route show
0.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.24.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  proto static 
128.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.24.1 dev tun0 
172.20.24.0/22 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.24.240 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.100  metric 1 
198.144.158.43 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

Unfortunately, I am still unable to connect to my TeamSpeak3 server which uses a UDP connection along with TCP. Since TCP is working fine, I am assuming there is something I am missing to get UDP working.

EDIT: The IP address is 192.168.0.100, on subnet 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.0.1 for the TS3 server. I am connecting to an IPVanish VPN server through the OpenVPN client on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your server `172.20.24.1` is redirecting your client default gateway and so your client tries to route everything over the VPN, which means you cannot connect to any services until your server knows where they are.